# Converting Streamlit App to exe file with nativefier certificate issues

Tags: python, streamlit

I have a streamlit app up and running on my PC and need to convert it to an exe file to share amongst my team. I'm currently following the tutorial of how to do this from this forum: https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-deployment-as-an-executable-file-exe-for-windows-macos-and-android/6812

It seems to work fine for everyone there, even when the app is just running on the localhost. However if I input the command

```
nativefier --name AppName.exe http://localhost:8501/ --platform windows --ignore-certificate --insecure
```

I get the following error: `GotError [RequestError]: unable to get local issuer certificate at ClientRequest`. I imagine that this is some sort of security issue with my work PC and I'm just trying to hunt down any workarounds that may be out there. As you can see I've tried to ignore the certificate and use the insecure option, however I still continue to get this error. Any ideas? Thanks so much for any advice.